# Why am I getting "Access Not Configured" error from YouTube Api v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube.net-api

I'm running some reports using the YouTube API v3 using the .net client library. On one certain YouTube account I'm getting this error

```
"Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nAccess Not Configured [403]\r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[Access Not Configured] Location[ - ] Reason[accessNotConfigured] Domain[usageLimits]\r\n]\r\n"
```

On other YouTube accounts I can run reports without getting this error.  Any ideas why?  Thanks!

A few things I've tried -
I've read threads online suggesting to check under the API \ Notification endpoints has the correct IP server address but it's empty and shows "Allowed Domains:No domains allowed". This also wouldn't explain why it works for some accounts and not others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you enabled Data API v3 and all other APIs you use from [devconsole](https://code.google.com/apis/console/), then use your client and and secret in the library while initiating the client.

There are [some examples in this sample](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/dotnet/upload_video.cs).

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked for me was to revert to the old version of the developer console at https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect and create a new project from there.

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks! Maybe there is a delay in activating a new API with the new dev console.