# Youtube Data API v3 - Bad Request - How to find what is wrong

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I want to retrieve Informations about Youtube Videos based on their id using php.

I have my API Key and I am trying this:

```
$res = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=<vid-id>&key=<my-key>");
echo $res;
```

But I get this warning:

> file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=<vid-id>&key=<my-key>): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

The response header looks like this:

```
["http_response_header"]=>
  array(10) {
[0]=>
   string(24) "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"
[1]=>
   string(45) "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"
[2]=>
   string(35) "Date: Sun, 25 May 2014 09:50:12 GMT"
[3]=>
   string(38) "Expires: Sun, 25 May 2014 09:50:12 GMT"
[4]=>
   string(33) "Cache-Control: private, max-age=0"
[5]=>
   string(31) "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff"
[6]=>
   string(27) "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN"
[7]=>
string(31) "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block"
[8]=>
   string(11) "Server: GSE"
[9]=>
   string(28) "Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic"
}
```

Now I am stuck. I have no idea what to do next to find out what is wrong. Am I missing something? Am I doing it wrong? I don't know.

Any hints?

**EDIT**

Thanks to hakre I was able to find the error message saying "accessnotconfigured".

Via this [Stackoverflow Entry (second response)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244218/why-am-i-getting-access-not-configured-error-from-youtube-api-v3) it occurred to me to just create a new project.

I then just skipped typing in a Referrer and now it works!

What the problem was, I don't know. I suspect it had something to do with the Referrer.

Comment: +1 For your first question providing a concrete example and showing how you did debug things. Also for your explanation how you fixed it and which sources you did use. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Youtube API has detailed error reporting with the HTTP response body, it's not within the response headers.

So whenever you get a HTTP error status code back from the Youtube API (code 400 to 499 or 4xx in short), you need to look into the JSON that has been provided as well.

To view that JSON, you can for a test quickly enter the URL into your browser. You'll get some JSON back which contains a better description what your error in making the request was.

If you want to do that programmatically in PHP, you need to tell the [*HTTP-wrapper* used by `file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) via the `$context` parameter (or by [setting the default context options](http://php.net/stream_context_set_default)) that it should not return `FALSE` on an HTTP error (which are all 400-599 codes), but to return the response body as well, see [`ingore_errros` in HTTP context options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.ignore-errors).

Example:

```
<?php

stream_context_set_default(['http' => ['ignore_errors' => true]]);
$res = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=<vid-id>&key=<my-key>");
echo $res;
```

This gives the following JSON output:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: part",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "part"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: part"
 }
}
```

(Yours might vary as you've got actual ID and KEY parameters which I have not)

Comment: Thank you! I edited my post with the solution i came up with.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the `picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api`. The problem with `file_get_contents()` is that it does return `false` when there are HTTP errors, so it does not provide access to the response body.
Using the URL in a browser allowed me to see the error message in the response body and understand the issue.